# WPF Singleton UserControl?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, singleton, single-instance

Is there a way to make UserControl a singleton?

ex:
I have a MainWindow and 2 UserControls {UserControl 'A' and UserControl 'B'}
MainWindow have 2 Buttons {Button 'UCA' and Button 'UCB'}
 
UserControl 'A' have a TextBox.
At startup I have UserControl 'A' loaded to MainWindow.
When I click Button 'UCB', UserControl 'B' will replace UserControl 'A' and when I click Button 'UCA', UserControl 'A' will replace UserControl 'B'.

My question is:
When UserControl 'A' is activated, I type "Test" on TextBox, then I switched to UserControl 'B'. I want when I switched back to UserControl 'A' the text on TextBox is still there. My solution is to create singleton UserControl but I don't know how to do that.

NB: Above is just simple example, what I want to achieve is more complicated than just maintain a text in TextBox when switched between UserControl. But, the point is how to call the same instance of UserControl without created a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you should have both user controls loaded in your MainWindow, and toggle their visibility when the buttons are pressed. For instance, if your UserControls are named `A` and `B` in Xaml, you'd do the following in codebehind for the `UCB.Click` handler:

```
B.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
A.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

and the opposite for the `UCA.Click` handler.

Comment: well, I forgot to mention I use a transition animation when changing UserControl. So, the code is much like : transiotion.Content = UserControl; when switched UserControl.